# Connecting Add Feature Class to Topology to Add Rule to Topology in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, topology, rule

[image]

I have a question regarding to how to connect the outputs of "Add Feature Class to Topology" to "Add Rule to Topology" in ModelBuilder.

As the picture shows, I want add a rule called Must Cover Each Other (Area-Area) in this Topology, I did "Add Feature Class to Topology" for both feature classes before adding this rule, however, it just allow me input one of the 2 outputs as "Input Topology".

How do I connect the 2 outputs of "Add Feature Class to Topology" to "Add Rule to Topology" in ModelBuilder correctly?

P.S.: I also tried to connect the feature classes and topology directly to "Add Rule to Topology", it returns an error and failed...

Answer (score 1):

To  answer your question (How do I connect the 2 outputs of "Add Feature Class to Topology" to "Add Rule to Topology"), The answer will be:

You can't, because "Add Rule to Topology" takes (just one topology and one or two feature classes) as Inputs. And you have (Two topologies) from ("Add Feature Class to Topology").

To apply the tool "Add Rule to Topology", you can apply directly this tool by using your topology (Change_check_district11) as input + the two feature classes (Buffer_district11 + Old_buffer_ditrict11)

Comment: Thank you, I tried using the tool "Add Rule to Topology" directly, but it always return and error and failed, any problem?

Comment: you welcome. It's difficult to define the source of the error, but in this case, maybe because the tool couldn't work based on your inputs